# Struts2 iterator tag - access specific object value from list of objects

Tags: list, jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

Is there a way to access an attribute of specific object from list of objects.

I've a List of Labs and each Lab object has multiple attributes. Using  tag, can we access value of attribute1 of Lab1 object from the list of labs?

Let's say: one of my `Lab` object has an attribute called `labname` with value "BP" and another lab object has `labname` of "A1c". 
Now, if I want to access the `labvalue` attribute of lab object with `labname` as "BP" how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a Map, that's easier, then you can exploit the [OGNL's List Selection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html)  feature:

> **Selecting From Collections**
>
> OGNL provides a simple way to use an expression to choose some
>   elements from a collection and save the results in a new collection.
>   We call this "selection," from the database term for choosing a subset
>   of rows from a table. For example, this expression:
>
> ```xml
> listeners.{? #this instanceof ActionListener}
> ```
>
> returns a list of all those listeners that are instances of the
>   ActionListener class.
>
> [...]

Then in the case you described, if you want to filter only the element of the list with the `labname` attribute equals to "BP" it would be:

```xml
<span>
    labvalue attribute for the (first, if any) laboratory with labname="BP" is : 
    <s:property value="labsList.{^ #this.labname == 'BP' }[0].labvalue" />
</span>
```

with no need of iterators at all.

You can also iterate a *projected* / *selected* list, btw ;)

```xml
<span>
    All labvalue attributes for all the laboratories with labname="BP" are : 
    <s:iterator value="labsList.{? #this.labname == 'BP' }" >
        <s:property value="labvalue" />
    </s:iterator>
</span>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

Give the list to the *value* attribute in s:iterator 
Define the object name in the **var** attribute

```
<s:iterator value="labsList" status="mbrindex" var="lab">
<s:property value="%{#lab.id}" />
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for your reply.. but, this one is still not solving my issue. Let's say - one of my Lab object has an attribute called labname with value "BP" and another lab object has labname of "A1c". Now, if I want to access the labvalue attribute of lab object with labname as "BP" how do I achieve it?

Comment: Do an    <s:if test="%{#lab.labName == 'BP'}"> and do the rest of the logic in that if condition.

Comment: This way if I've 20 lab objects and need only 2 of them , I need to iterate more than 2 times through the list. I don't want to do that and would like to know if there is a way to directly access the list for specific object.

Comment: I think there is no direct way to access something from a list using iterator tag. So, the alternative I found is push the list elements to a HashMap with Object name as HashMap key and from <s:iterator> tag I can access directly required object's attributes.