# How to draw multiple HTML Tables from a single Collection with <s:iterator>?

Tags: java, html, collections, struts2, ognl

Assume I have two tables, Monday and Tuesday. I want to populate these tables according to a property of the object. Thus:

```xml
<s:iterator value="trainings">
 <table>
   <tr><th>Monday</th></tr>

   <s:if test="weekday.toString().equals('MONDAY')">
     <tr>
       <td>
          <s:property value="title" />
       </td>
    </tr>
   </s:if>
 </table>

 <table>
   <tr><th>Tuesday</th></tr>

   <s:if test="weekday.toString().equals('TUESDAY')">
     <tr>
       <td>
          <s:property value="title" />
       </td>
    </tr>
   </s:if>
 </table>

</s:iterator>
```

How can I make this work correctly? Thank you

EDIT:

```java
public class Training {    
    private Weekday weekday;        
    ....        
}

public Enum Weekday {        
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    ...        
}
```

Comment: Please show the structure of your Java objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate two different tables from a single source (that should be better to split server-side, in the action), you usually need to iterate the collection twice:

```xml
    <table>
        <tr><th>Monday</th></tr>
  <s:iterator value="trainings">
      <s:if test="weekday.toString().equals('MONDAY')">
        <tr><td><s:property value="title" /></td></tr>
      </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr><th>Tuesday</th></tr>
  <s:iterator value="trainings">
      <s:if test="weekday.toString().equals('TUESDAY')">
        <tr><td><s:property value="title" /></td></tr>
      </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

To avoid executing the `<s:if>` multiple times, you can use [OGNL's List Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23677665/1654265):

```xml
    <table>
        <tr><th>Monday</th></tr>
  <s:iterator value="trainings.{? #this.weekday.toString() == 'MONDAY' }">
        <tr><td><s:property value="title" /></td></tr>
  </s:iterator>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr><th>Tuesday</th></tr>
  <s:iterator value="trainings.{? #this.weekday.toString() == 'TUESDAY' }">
        <tr><td><s:property value="title" /></td></tr>
  </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

that results in a smaller and cleaner HTML code.